# Structures in C finding element larger than certain varriable

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Hello i am trying to find an element with the highest price after year 2007 using data structs in C tried everything all sorts of statements, but i cannot seem to do it. Here is a piece of the code. Could someone please offer a suggestions to my problem ?

```
LIST *sortKM1(LIST *pFirst)
{
    LIST *b = pFirst;
    LIST *p = pFirst;
    LIST *b1, *bus1 = NULL;

    for (p = pFirst; p != NULL; p = p->pNext)
    {

            if ((b->body.price) < (p->body.price)&& (p->body.year)>2007))
            {
                b = p;
            }

    }
    b1 = newElement(bus1, b->body);
    return b1;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?  Is it not finding the highest element?  I notice you're using `bus1` when it's only been set to `NULL`, that COULD be a problem (and I suspect it is) but I don't know what `newElement` is doing

Comment: It looks as if you are comparing two copies of the same data.  i.e. `LIST *b and *p are both created using the same argument: LIST *pFirst.

Comment: I find the most "expensive element" but not above year 2007. Had a couple of test structures which is most expensive and is made in 2005 and it shows as the result.

Comment: @ryyker they are initialized that way but `p` iterates over the list, `p` should be set to `b->pNext` but that doesn't appear to be the root issue here

Comment: @sedavidw it is just a function to relocate memory for the new element as the result.

Comment: You are comparing with `b->body.price` but you haven't checked that the initial `b`'s year is above 2007.

Comment: The line: `b = p;` sets the pointer to all the information represented by b to p.  That is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: There is an extra `)` just after 2007 in your code?

Comment: @Steephen yes there is my error when i eddit the statement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplification should solve the problems, which are that if *none* of the record years are > 2007 the answer is incorrect, and, if the *first* record is <= 2007 but is the highest price, that too is incorrect. Also, you don't need to create a new record: just return the pointer to the best record.

If no record is found matching the year criterion, `NULL` is returned, if success then the record pointer is returned.

```
LIST *sortKM1(LIST *pFirst) {
    LIST *b = NULL, *p;
    int price = -1;              // match the var type to the LIST struct

    for (p = pFirst; p != NULL; p = p->pNext) 
    {
        if (price < p->body.price && p->body.year > 2007)
        {
            price = p->body.price;
            b = p;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but i want to do it for just one element. How should i break the cycle ?

Comment: I don't understand. This returns a pointer to one element (or none). The cycle doesn't break because it needs to look at all the elements.

Comment: Works great thank you @Weather Vane  : ) . I removed the "return b" so it does not return its value numerous times.

Comment: @VeselinLalov functions, in C, cannot return more than once in a call, a return ends the execution of the function. They can have multiple return statements but only one is ever executed.

Answer (score 0):

if ((b->body.price) < (p->body.price)&& (p->body.year)>2007))
 you have one extra bracket at the end. Can this be a problem? you may need to have: if ((b->body.price) < (p->body.price)&& (p->body.year)>2007)

Comment: no it does not provide a solution. I dont know if i can say(p->body.year)>2007)

Comment: I probably should use a different function to take all elements above 2007 and pass them here in LIST *sortKM1(LIST *pFirst) ?

Comment: that might be a solution too but honestly I cannot see any problem in checking it in the same if statement....

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on a comment:
Suppose `pFirst->body.price` is the highest price in the entire
data structure, but `pFirst->body.year` is 2005.
Because you initially set `b = pFirst,`
you will never find the highest price after 2007, because none
of them will exceed `pFirst->body.price`.
Instead you will end up saying that `pFirst` is the record after 2007
with the highest price, which is simply wrong.

To fix this, I would recommend indicating in some way that initially
*no* entry of the list is selected as the "highest price from 2007".
For example, you could set `b = NULL` initially.

That also means you must have some additional logic inside the loop
to handle the case where no record after the year 2007 has yet been found,
and logic outside the loop to handle the case where there is no
record after 2007 in the entire list.
The logic outside the loop might be as simple as returning NULL,
but the caller has to be prepared to receive that answer.

The logic inside the loop may be simpler if it looks something like this:

```
for (p = pFirst; p != NULL; p = p->pNext)
{
  if (p->body.year > 2007)
  {
    if( ... ) // <-- replace '...' with necessary logic
    {
      b = p;
    }
  }
}
```

I would prefer it even more if the variables were given names that give
a better idea how they are actually to be used, for example
`highest_found` instead of `b`.